# find out all the record triggered flow that are acting upon any object?

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

when you goto the Flow list view in case of record trigger flow, we can see the type of the flow , but I can’t see to which object the flow is acting upon in list view .Our requirement is to find out all the record triggered flow that are acting upon any object??

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible without some custom coding. As far as I can tell, the only way to see this information (without opening each individual flow) is downloading the metadata and searching for the `<start>` element in the xml, which will include an `<object>` element within. Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    ...
    <start>
        ...
        <object>Task</object>
        ...
    </start>
    ...
</Flow>
```

Knowing this, you can write a script that will iterate over the flow files and retrieve the object value from the xml.

I wish there was an easier way but I don't believe one exists.